# Set ItemSource and DisplayMemberPath of ComboBox in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I'm working myself through a [Tutorial](http://buksbaum.us/2011/08/20/gentle-introduction-to-mefpart-one/) for MEF ([Managed Extensibility Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx)) for C#, but can't get the exaple-project wo work, because of those two code-lines (in the linked tutorial they can be found beneath the big picture of the interface):

```
cbTransformationOptions.ItemsSource = _tranformationEngine.Transformers;
cbTransformationOptions.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
```

the mentioned `cbTransformationOptions` is a ordinary ComboBox. The code won't compile, i'm getting the following errors:

```
'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' does not contain a definition for 'ItemsSource' 
and no extension method 'ItemsSource' accepting a first argument of type
'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive 
or an assembly reference?)

'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' does not contain a definition for 'DisplayMemberPath'
and no extension method 'DisplayMemberPath' accepting a first argument of type
'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive 
or an assembly reference?)
```

What i figured out untill now, is, that both of those statements are somehow linked to WPF / XAML (i found some references on StackOverflow)- but i don't have any experience on that topic, so those answers didn't help me at all.

How do I get the code to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Windows.Forms is the wrong namespace you need to create a wpf project.

Comment: Thank you. I copyed the code to a new wpf-project, and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial is describing a WPF project, whereas you seem to be attempting to compile the code against a Windows Forms project.

WPF is an alternative presentation technology to Windows Forms, and is a huge subject in itself. I recommend you purchase a book on WPF if you wish to build WPF projects.

I don't know how experienced you are in .NET, but Pro WPF in C# 2010 provides excellent coverage.